# Open Microsoft Edge while running app in Hololens

Tags: windows, pdf, unity-game-engine, microsoft-edge, hololens

I want to open Microsoft Edge while running an app with the HoloLens. In my particular case, I'm developing a simple 2D app in Unity, where the idea is to press a button and open a pdf file, image, etc. Currently I've managed to open these files with the WWW class by pressing a button, but everytime I do it the app gets closed...

Is it possible achieve it? what would I need to implement in order to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To open EDGE or the default web browser you can use `Application.OpenURL`
 https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html

In any case your app will go to the background, In case you need to show a website inside your app you will need to use any Plugin/Asset like this one https://github.com/gree/unity-webview that sadly doesn't support Windows.

Comment: Application.OpenURL crashes the unity application on my side. My file is stored in Application.PersistentDataPath. Do you have any additionnal tip? Thank you very much.